# Is the Lorentz force the divergence of a symmetric tensor?

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity

The conservation of momentum and energy in electromagnetism is usually written as 
$$ \partial_\nu T^{\mu \nu} + \eta^{\mu \rho} f_\rho = 0 $$
where $T^{\mu\nu}$ is the electromagnetic stress-energy tensor and $f_\rho$ is the Lorentz force.

However the conservation of momentum and energy in general relativity is stated as the divergence of the total stress-energy tensor being zero. So is there a symmetric tensor $T_\text{Lorentz}^{\mu\nu}$ which divergence is $\eta^{\mu \rho}  f_\rho$, so that $\partial_\nu(T^{\mu\nu}+T_\text{Lorentz}^{\mu\nu})=0$ ?

$T_\text{Lorentz}^{\mu\nu}$ would measure the energy and momentum of charged particules.

Comment: Doesn't this answer your question? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_formulation_of_classical_electromagnetism#Charge_continuum

Comment: I think you basically answered your question in the last sentence.

Comment: @Javier Then I expect a formula of $T^{\mu\nu}_\text{Lorentz}$ as a function of the 4-current $J^\mu$, but I can't find it.